# Measure theoretic interpretation of sampling a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

According to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368492/about-sampling-and-random-variables),  $N$ independent, identical draws from a random variable $Y$ is the same thing as one draw from each of $N$ independent, identically random variables $Y_n$. I am struggling to formulate this observation rigorously from the perspective of measure theory.

I guess sampling from $Y$ n times, can on one hand be thought of as a sequence of events $\omega_n$ from one sample space $\Omega$ or it can be thought of as a realization of $n$ iid random variables. In what sense are they equivalent mathematically?

Comment: draws at different times represent different random variables. Its wrong to say that one can draw independently $n$ times from the *same* random variable, as a random variable is never independent of itself

Comment: Why wouldn't one just view different draws as different events from a single random variable?

Answer (score 2):

Let us recall that, from the point of view of measure theory, a *probability space* is a triple $(\Omega ,\mathcal A,\mu
)$, where $\Omega $ is a set, $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma $-algebra of subsets of $\Omega $, and $\mu $ is a positive
measure defined on $\mathcal A$, and satisfying $\mu (\Omega )=1$.

On the other hand, a *random variable* is nothing but a function
$$
  Y:\Omega \to {\mathbb R}
  $$
which is measurable in the sense that $Y^{-1}((-\infty ,a))\in \mathcal A$, for all $a\in {\mathbb R}$.

Incidentally, although Statisticians will likely disagree, there is absolutely nothing *random* about a random variable!

I any case, given $Y$, as above,
in order to formalize the concept of $n$ independent and identically distributed random variables, one must replace
the probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal A,\mu )$ with $(\Omega _n,\mathcal A_n,\mu _n)$, where

- $
    \Omega _n = \Omega \times \Omega \times \cdots \times \Omega ,
    $
- $\mathcal A_n$ is the $\sigma $-algebra generated by the collection of sets of the form
  $E_1\times E_2\times \cdots \times E_n$, where each $E_i$ belongs to $\mathcal A$,
- $\mu _n$ is the product measure, namely the unique measure defined on $\mathcal A_n$ such that
  $
    \mu _n(E_1\times E_2\times \cdots \times E_n)= \mu (E_1) \mu (E_2) \ldots \mu (E_n).
    $

Once this is done, we may consider, for each $k=1,2,\ldots ,n$, the random variable $Y_k$ defined by
$$
  Y_k(\omega _1,\omega _2,\ldots , \omega _n) = Y(\omega _k),
  $$
and one may now easily prove that the $Y_k$ are indeed independent, and that they are identically distributed, in the
sense that the push-forward measures on ${\mathbb R}$ given by $(Y_k)_*(\mu _n)$ all coincide with $Y_*(\mu )$.

Recalling that the two alternatives presented by the OP are:

1. a realization of $n$ iid random variables,
2. a sequence of events from the sample space,

I must say that I struggle to make precise mathematical sense of the sentence "a realization of a random variable".  To
me, the only possible meaning of this is "choosing some $\omega $ in $\Omega $ and computing $Y(\omega )$", which
doesn't seem to be an act worthy of such a pompous name.

Nevertheless, according to this logic, (1) should then be formally interpreted as choosing some $\omega =(\omega
_1,\omega _2,\ldots , \omega _n)$ in $\Omega _n$, and computing $Y_1(\omega ),Y_2(\omega ),\ldots ,Y_n(\omega )$.

On the other hand, (2) should be interpreted as preforming $n$ experiments of choosing $\omega $ in $\Omega $, and
computing $Y(\omega )$.

So, if we collect the $n$ chosen $\omega $'s from the paragraph above into an $n$-tuple $(\omega _1,\omega _2,\ldots ,
\omega _n)$, we see that (2) is precisely equivalent to (1).

Comment: Your formalization is not the only one, so instead of 'must replace', I would say 'can replace'. An IID collection of rvs can also be defined on a unique probability space: it is sufficient for the sub-$\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(Y_n)$ to be mutually independent. Also, I find it likely for statisticians to agree with you. Someone who very likely would not be amused are, in my opinion, some physicists.

Comment: Wouldn't $\Omega_n$ be a unique probability space?  How else would you build n iid random variables in a canonical way?

Comment: I am referring to a single $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ s.t. $Y_1,...,Y_n$ on it satisfy [mutual independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_random_variables) @Ruy

Comment: Ok, I know what are independent rv's, but you didn't address my remarks.

Comment: @ Ruy Here is what I thought as a general way to conceive '$n$ IID random variables'. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space. Let $(Y_{k})_{k\leq n}$ be a collection of mutually independent measurable functions $Y_k:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $P(Y^{-1}_k(A))=Q(A),\,\forall k\leq n,\,\forall A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for some probability distribution $Q$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. This definition is (I think) valid for this purpose. So what you said is completely valid too, but not the only formalization.

Comment: @Snoop,  when you say "Let $(Y_k)_k$ ..." I understand that you are assuming the existence of the $Y_k$ but I think the point is how to build these in a canonical way out of a single $Y$.

Comment: Ok, I think I am getting your argument then